# How to make a SwipeRefreshLayout not swipeable?

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

I have a refresh button on one of my activities. Whenever a user presses that button I want to use the SwipeRefreshLayout refreshing animation, **but I do not want the user to be able to swipe down to refresh the screen**. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: then why are using it !!

Comment: @AtefHares because I want the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried `swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);` ? And then you could simply call the `setRefreshing(true)` and `setRefreshing(false)` in your button's listener

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried;

```
  //button clicked...
  //show loader, disable further pulltorefresh requests
  //do some timed task
  pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(true);

  //Task done...
  //hide loader, allow pulltorefresh requests
  pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
```

I use in a fragment;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

    pullToRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.pullToRefresh);
    pullToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

        @Override

        public void onRefresh() {

            refreshContent();


        }

    });


    Button refresh = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.refreshMethod);
    refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            refreshContent();

        }
    });

    return view;

}



refreshContent() {

   //call Async task via RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {}

    new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();

}


 class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

   private Exception exception;
   protected void onPreExecute() {

      recycler.clearOnScrollListeners();
      pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(true);

   }

   protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {

      //do task like get JSON from server
      //try sleep for a bit
      try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
      } catch (InterruptedException error) {
      }

   }



   protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

           //do post stuff
           //hide pullfresh, full refresh view done
           pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);


   }

 }
```

Comment: I would still be able to swipe it down though.

Comment: I use the above to show pullrefresh loader which disables further pullrefresh instances until task is complete and hide, re-enables pullrefresh

Comment: BENN1TH would it be any different for an AppCompactActivity?

Comment: no just build in the onCreate(){} method once you inflate the view